# How to read multiple text files in a folder with Python?

Tags: python, io, file-handling

I have looked at multiple questions & answers across SO, as well as other platforms pertaining to reading text files in a folder, but unfortunately none seems to work for me at the moment. I have multiple text files in a folder and would like to read them all, and put each text file as a string into a new list `new_list`.

```
path = "MyNews_AccidentDataset/News_txt.txt"
all_files = os.listdir(path)
```

Using this gives me `all_files` as a list with names of all text files

```
 '0185_Man dies after 100ft turbine fall  .txt',
 '0131_Deaths_from_Working_with_Wind_Energy - Copy (5) - Copy.txt',
 '0001_BENDING_WITH_THE_WIND._Modern_Power_System_N.txt']
.......
```

However, when I use `open()` to read the file,

```
new_list = []
    for fle in all_files:
       # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
       with open(fle) as f:
          text = f.read()
          new_list.append(text)
```

I get the following error:-

```
with open(fle) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0106_Car_vehicles_part_falls_on_the_roadway.txt'
```

although the mentioned file exists in the folder.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Using complete path as in suggested comment by @bexi

```
for fle in all_files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(os.path.join(path, fle)) as f:
      text = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some other comments and answers I got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 643: ordinal not in range(128)`. Finally, I could successfully solve the issue by setting the read mode as binary `"rb"` instead of `"r"`:-

```
for fle in all_files:
   # open the file and then call .read() to get the text
   with open(os.path.join(path, fle),"rb") as f:
      text = f.read()
      new_list.append(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose all files ends with .txt:

```
new_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(<path to your folder>):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt')
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
                new_list.append(text)
```

Comment: Is the first `for` statement necessary in case there are things other than text files in the folder?